# How to create multidimensional array from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, ienumerable

Is there some elegant way to create multidimensional array from IEnumerable. I know how to write function like this

```
double[,] GetMultidimesionalArray(IEnumerable<double> ienumerable, int nRows, int nColumns)
{
   var toReturn = new double[nRows,nColumns];
   var e = ienumerable.Select((x, i) => new { el = x, id = i });
   foreach (var item in e)
      toReturn[item.id / nColumns, item.id % nColumns] = item.el;
   return toReturn;
}
```

which doesn't looks very nice. An elegant way to do this would be:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(ienumerable.ToArray(), 0, toReturn, 0, nRows * nColumns * sizeof(double));
```

but this is not good since the additional array (ienumerable.ToArray()) is created in memory.

So, I am looking for elegant way to solve it (like a second one), but also efficient in terms of time/memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, LINQ does not deal directly with 2D arrays, so a loop would be required if you insist on having a `double[,]` return type. Your approach is fine; an alternative could be to use two nested loops to avoid computing indexes with division and modulo:

```
double[,] GetMultidimesionalArray(IEnumerable<double> ienumerable, int nRows, int nColumns) {
    var res = new double[nRows,nColumns];
    using (var iter = ienumerable.GetEnumerator()) {
        for (var r = 0 ; r != nRows ; r++) {
            for (var c = 0 ; c != nColumns; c++) {
                if (!iter.MoveNext()) {
                    break;
                }
                res[r,c] = iter.Current;
            }
        }
    }
   return res;
}
```

This approach does not throw an exception when the sequence has too many or too few elements compared to the expected size of nRows × nColumns. In addition, its code structure reflects the structure of the return value (i.e. two nested loops populating a 2D array) which makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: This solution is better since it doesn't compute indices as in my solution. But, I was hopping to find more elegant solution like the one with `BlockCopy`, which doesn't mess up with indices, for loop, etc. Do you know if something like this exists?

Comment: @Dejan The nature of `IEnumerable<T>` makes that impossible. The only way to access items is by iterating through them. There's no block copy potential there because there is no block.

Comment: @itsme86 Ok, I cannot use block copy since there is no block with IEnumerable. But it doesn't mean that other function could not exist which dumps all elements of IEnumerable to memory starting from the particular address.

Comment: @Dejan I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "starting from the particular address". Do you mean for the source or destination? If you mean destination, that's what yours and dasblinklight's code does now. If you mean source, there's absolutely no guarantee that an `IEnumerable<T>`'s items are contiguous in memory. Consider `IEnumerable<int> Get99s(int num) { while (num-- > 0) yield return 99; }` How would your hypothetical method handle that?

Comment: @itsme86 I mean destination. E.g. Dump(IEnumerable<T> src, Array dst). And that function will go through all IEnumerable src element and write each one in succesive memory location of dst array. And you can use doule[],List<double>, double[,], etc for your destination. My question was if similar function exists, since I guess that it can be implemented.

Comment: You're stuck with `.ToArray()` and `.ToList()` for that purpose if you want built-in functionality.